# How to override Magento 2 extension helper file?

Tags: php, magento2

I have try to override magento 2 extension helper file but it's not working.

Can anyone tell me how to override magento2 extension helper file?

I need to override Data.php file in my custom extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Try with below code for helper override.

Step 1 :

```
app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Catalog\Data" />
</config>
```

Step : 2

```
Let’s rewrite getProduct() function of class Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data. We will just log some message on var/log/debug.log for this test.

<?php

namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Catalog;

class Data extends \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
{    
    /**
     * Retrieve current Product object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|null
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Helper Override Test');

        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
?>
```

[More details refer this link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-override-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-using-plugin-preference/)